# Is it possible to reattach to a detached process using child_process with Node or IOJS

Tags: node.js

I have a program that spawns a server for a video game, 'Counter-Strike Global Offensive' to be exact.

The `child_process` spawns with the flag `detached: true`

Everything works and the server goes up, then the `process id` of the child is saved in a MYSQL Database but say I wanted to change the level or something, how can I reattach to that process id and send it a command? Looking through the `child_process` documentation it does not seem like there is any option to reattach to do so? Any information would be fantastic thanks.